# control downloading (.htaccess?)

Tags: .htaccess, permissions, download

I need to protect a .zip file from being downloaded w/o permission.

I would like to be able to provide a direct link to the .zip download to those who have access to the files.

```
<filesmatch .zip>
 order deny, allow
 deny from all
</filesmatch>
```

does not seem to work. It prevents direct links, but I am not sure how to provide the download now.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend placing the files in a separate directory. You can secure this directory with a password using basic authentication.

Your .htaccess will then be as follows:

```
AuthName "Log in to continue"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/to/your/.htpasswd
<limit GET POST>
  require valid-user
</limit>
```

Your .htpasswd should contain a line for every user that is allowed to authenticate:

```
test:R.NyWzK/TEEvo
```

(this is the line for username: test, password: test).

You can find .htpassword generators everywhere on the internet. For example:

http://home.flash.net/cgi-bin/pw.pl

Answer (score 0):

I actually just used

```
<FilesMatch .zip>
    order deny, allow
    deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

in addition to using this little PHP script when a user is authenticated

```
if($_POST['subDownload']){
    if(file_exists('./photo_sets/photo_set_1.zip')){
        $FileName = "./photo_sets/photo_set_1.zip";
      header("Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed");
      header("Content-Length: " . filesize($FileName));
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$FileName\"");
      header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
      readfile($FileName);
    }
```

seems to do the trick...